# Bulkloading schema less entities on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, bulk-load

The new bulkloader added into SDK 1.3.4 works great for models that
have a schema. For models inheriting db.Expando (or loosely defined
schemas) i would like to understand what i would have to do to bulk
upload them.

I defined a custom connector, that implemented the ConnectorInterface
and converted my data to the python dict required. How can i use this
dict to define entities that get uploaded to the data store ?

In the documentation there seems to be a post_import_function that can
be used to return the entities that get uploaded. Is there an example
on how this function is used ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- kind: foo
  connector: fooconnector
  post_import_function: post_transform.post_import_fn
```

where,

```
def post_import_fn(input_dict, entity_instance, bulkload_state):
    .....
```

is the function that is used for post_import. Hope this is useful for someone else.